# Is a diode's forward voltage stable enough to be used as a reference voltage?

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-reference

Assuming a resistor is in series with a diode (say, a 1N4001) so that the diode has around 1mA of current, will its forward voltage be usable as a voltage reference to within 1% (relative to itself over time and with ambient temperature changing by 10F max)? The voltage doesn't matter, as long as it doesn't change to a noticeable degree.

Comment: The datasheet of the diode will tell.

Comment: Are you asking whether it will change with change with temperature, with age, from diode to diode, with something else?

Comment: Change with regard to what? Temperature?  Generally no, it is a lousy voltage reference. If you have a constant current you are better off putting this over a resistor.

Comment: You have to identify what can cause the drop to vary when operating. Here, it's at least forward current, power dissipation and temperature. Then you can look these factors up in the datasheets, find out what the effect of them will be and weigh that up against your requirements. That should be a task for you, I'm afraid.

Comment: If it would be that easy to get a 1% stable reference voltage, a reference voltage IC wouldn't be as expensive as they are (compared to a diode).

Comment: 10% sure, 1% not really. for 1% you're better off with something like TL431

Comment: @Jasen For clarification, I need it to be accurate within 1% of itself over time, not within 1% of the datasheet spec. Does it vary by 10% over time?

Comment: it'd take fairly exterme temperature variations to get 10% change,  but 30 degrees will get you 1% of 600mV

Comment: Use a diode as a diode. Use a voltage reference as a voltage reference. Problem solved?

Comment: "Assuming a **constant**, preferably low current (1mA) is applied..." - then you don't need a diode, just use a 1% resistor. "...to within 1%" - why do you need 1%?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Acquiring new parts is difficult for me at the moment. I have diodes, I do not have voltage references.

Comment: If cost is an issue get a [TL431](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TL431-D.PDF) shunt reference. If you need to salvage it,you can find them in "almost" any switching power supply, connected to an optoisolator on the output side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is a diode's forward voltage stable enough to be used as a reference
>   voltage?

No, it will change with temperature: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://xtronics.com/wiki/Temperature_Compensation.html)

At 25 degC and a bias of 5.1 mA (for example) the voltage will typically (that's typical and not always) be about 627 mV. At 30 degC the voltage will have dropped to about 618 mV - that's a change of 1.4% for a minor difference in temperature. In voltage reference terms that's a stability of 2878 ppm/degC. Compare this to just fairly cheap voltage references having a drift of 50 ppm/degC.

> Assuming a constant, preferably low current (1mA) is applied to a
>   diode

If you have a constant current source then apply it to a resistor and you'll get pretty much stable results compared to the diode.

Comment: but if it's a slightly variable source the diode voltage wavers less than the resistor voltage would.

Comment: @Jasen The op said "constant current source".

Comment: sure, but this is the real world. I mean a diode rejects fluctuations in the current source better than a resistor does, but it also makes a better thermometer.

Comment: @Jasen A real world constant current source has what type of spec would you say?

Comment: @Andyaka I did not. I likely used confusing terminology, but I meant having the diode in series with an unchanging resistance. I.E, not having it power a load that changes. As mentioned, if I had a constant current source, I'd use that as my reference voltage.

Comment: @Daffy are you aware that you can buy shunt references that would produce about 1.2 volts from the current you mentioned?

Comment: @andyaka, finite impedance, PSRR, temperature stability, magnetic sensitivity, compliance, capacitance, there are so many ways a circuit can be non-ideal, I've probably missed some.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some instrument schematics, that use LED diode as power indicator and voltage source.  Could the LED be a better alternative? Search for current, voltage source schematics examples, perhaps you will the answer.

P.S: The "instrument" is the LeCroy scope differential probe, not a toy.

[image: http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/equipment-and-tools/248505-differential-probe-reverese-engineered.html]

Source : http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/equipment-and-tools/248505-differential-probe-reverese-engineered.html

Comment: in this circit the temperature curve of the led and the transistor cancel each other's effect, I wonder to what extent this device is sensitive to bright lights.

Answer (score 1):

You can design BandGap voltage references, using multiple diodes running at different currents (thus different current densities and thus difference temperature coefficients. Some opamp circuit is needed to extract the CTAT. You combine the PTAT and a proper amount of the CTAT, and extract a very stable voltage reference. If you do this, please honor Paul Brokaw for the invention.